# How can simultaneous sinusoidal equations be solved?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have come across a set of simultaneous equations which I can't figure out how to solve. I have 3 equations and only two unknowns, but they are angular quantities and feature in the equations as sinusoidal functions of the angular quantities.

The system of equations is:

$$ \begin{Bmatrix}\cos\psi\sin\theta+\cos\theta\sin\phi\sin\psi \\ \sin\psi\sin\theta-\cos\psi\cos\theta\sin\phi \\ \cos\phi\cos\theta \end{Bmatrix} = \begin{Bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{Bmatrix} $$

Where: x, y, z and psi are known and phi and theta are unknown.

Is it possible to rearrange these equations to solve for theta and phi using the other terms?

Comment: Maple can solve your system

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, maybe it is not so much instructive to resort to computer, and in many cases the why of their answer shall be understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is not always solvable. The two first equations factor as
$$\tag{1} \begin{pmatrix} \cos\psi & \sin\psi \\ \sin\psi & -\cos\psi \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \sin\theta \\ \cos\theta \sin\phi \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $$
where the first factor is just a reflection in a line through the origin, so
$$ \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi = x^2 + y^2 $$
Squaring the third equation gives
$$ \cos^2\theta \cos^2\phi = z^2 $$
and adding these equations give
$$ x^2+y^2+z^2 = \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta(\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\phi) = 1 $$
so your system only has a solution when $(x,y,z)$ is a point on the unit sphere.

If your constants satisfy this, a natural approach would be to divide out the reflection matrix in $(1)$, producing
$$ \begin{cases} \sin \theta = x' \\ \cos\theta\sin\phi = y' \\ \cos\theta \cos\phi = z \end{cases} $$
for some $x'$ and $y'$. From here you get $\theta = \arcsin x'$ and and $\phi = \arctan \frac{y'}{z}$, both up to a choice of quadrants that have to be made in a matching way, possibly just by trial and error.

Comment: What do you mean by reflection matrix? I've never heard of this concept before.

Comment: @Era: The 2×2 matrix in the first equation is a rotation matrix with one column negated. It represents the transformation of a rotation around the origin followed by a reflection about one of the coordinate axes -- which has the same result as reflecting about some slanted line through the origin. But all you really need to know here is that it is invertible (and, in fact, its own inverse).

Comment: I see what you mean. I actually got to this set of equations from a 3D rotation matrix. Does the x' signify the first derivative of x or does it have some other meaning?

Comment: @Era: $x'$ and $y'$ are just names for the coordinates you get when you transform $(x,y)$ by the inverse of the 2×2 matrix.

Comment: Thank you, just to check my understanding that would make x' = x(cos(psi) + sin(psi))

Comment: @Era: No, $x'$ would be $x\cos\psi + y\sin\psi$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   x  \\
   y  \\
   z  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\cos \psi \sin \theta  + \cos \theta \sin \phi \sin \psi }  \\
   {\sin \psi \sin \theta  - \cos \psi \cos \theta \sin \phi }  \\
   {\cos \phi \cos \theta }  \\
\end{array}} \right) =  \\ 
  = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\sin \theta \cos \psi  + \cos \theta \sin \phi \sin \psi }  \\
   {\sin \theta \sin \psi  - \cos \theta \sin \phi \cos \psi }  \\
   {\cos \theta \cos \phi }  \\
\end{array}} \right) =  \\ 
  = \sin \theta \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\cos \psi }  \\
   {\sin \psi }  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right) + \cos \theta \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\sin \phi \sin \psi }  \\
   { - \sin \phi \cos \psi }  \\
   {\cos \phi }  \\
\end{array}} \right) =  \\ 
  = \sin \theta \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\cos \psi }  \\
   {\sin \psi }  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right) + \cos \theta \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\sin \phi \cos \left( {\psi  + \pi /2} \right)}  \\
   {\sin \phi \sin \left( {\psi  + \pi /2} \right)}  \\
   {\cos \phi }  \\
\end{array}} \right) =  \\ 
  = \sin \theta \;{\bf u} + \cos \theta \;{\bf v} \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

where $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ are  given in spherical coordinates, and can be seen to be
unitary vectors and orthogonal to each other.
Their combination with $sin \theta$ and $cos \theta$ is therefore a circle in their plane.
For the system to have solutions, the vector $\bf p=(x,y,z)$ shall be on the unitary sphere.
That given, there will be multiple solutions for the three angles, corresponding to the 
infinite main circles passing through $\bf p$.